# SwiftUI preview's subviews are unselectable when embedded in NavigationView

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

When I embed my view's body inside of a `NavigationView` I lose all ability to select subviews within the preview window, as well as the reverse ability of selecting code to trigger and display the blue border around the associated subview in the preview. It only shows a blue border around the entire `NavigationView` no matter what or where I click. Is this a bug? If not, what am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** Per the request of the comments below, here is a simple example:

```
struct FooView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Label("Try")
                Label("Selecting")
                Label("These")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Probably a bug or "feature"...

Comment: The example is embedding literally anything in a `NavigationView` and trying to select it.

Comment: show us the code you are having these issues with, so we can have a look and help you.

Comment: Alright, example added.

Comment: I think you should wrapper your text with ```VStack{``` or ```HStack{``` from any view container.

Comment: That is because with this setup you are presenting a [stack of Views](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationview) the `Text` is the whole screen/column. They aren't rows as would be assumed.

Comment: Ok, my point is that if you put anything in a `NavigationStack`, whether it's HStack, VStack, a container of buttons, labels, etc. you cannot highlight them in the preview or vice versa. I've updated the example.

Comment: Almost a year later and I am seeing this issue with Xcode 14.0 beta as well.