# Xcode 12 SwiftUI Preview not highlighting Views embedded in NavigationView

Tags: xcode, swiftui, uinavigationbar

Using the SwiftUI Xcode preview pane, I can click on the rendered views and see the code responsible for that view highlighted in the code pane (and vice versa). However, when I embed the view in a `NavigationView` or sometimes even addding a `.navigationBarTitle()` to the root view, I can't do that anymore. All views in the Navigation group just becomes one big view and the previewer can't identify the separate underlying pieces anymore.

Is this a bug? Is there a way to get around it? It's a really useful feature and most of my views sit in some kind of Navigation object.

#### Working

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct NavSample: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Hello, World!")
  }
}

struct NavSample_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    NavSample()
  }
}
```

#### Not Working

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct NavSample: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {          // Adding this
      Text("Hello, World!")
    }
  }
}

struct NavSample_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    NavSample()
  }
}
```

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68075728/14351818